# How would I go about making a Text represent a variable from another view (swiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

sorry if this is a noob question, but I recently started getting into Xcode development and I can't seem to figure out this one problem.

So basically when the user clicks on the song, the app would pull up a sheet, with the album art, song title, and artist. All that is working, except the song title, album art and artist. I figured that using an EnvironmentObject would be the way to go. so I put:

```
import Foundation

import Combine

class NowPlayingData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var songName:String = "Not Playing"
}
```

On the NowPlaying page, which would show the info, and I have this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NowPlaying: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var songName: NowPlayingData
    @State private var volume = 0.1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Image("NA")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .shadow(radius: 50)
                Text("\(songName)")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                Text("")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            }
            Slider(value: $volume)
                .padding(.horizontal, 5.0)
            mediaControls()
        }
    }
}

struct NowPlaying_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NowPlaying()
    }
}
```

On building it however, I get this error: Cannot convert value of type 'NowPlayingData' to expected argument type 'String'

I also have a button that would be like `self.songName = "Bud Like You`

Thanks, and sorry if this isn't formatted correctly or hard to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error comes from using "songName" which is a NowPlayingData, instead of a String in:

```
     Text("\(songName)")
```

What you want is the String of the NowPlayingData, which is:

```
     Text("\(self.songName.songName)")
```

I suggest you rename your var to make more sense, eg:

```
@EnvironmentObject var playingData: NowPlayingData
```